# jQuery calendar, doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to implement jQuery calender at my homepage: This is the way I do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.core"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="core.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

In the same folder I have all the javascripts that are required. But when I try to click inside the form, no calendar is showing. Why? Thanks!

Comment: Are the paths to the scripts correct? What errors are you getting in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also specify `type` for your script tags. Have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KsGHV/).

Answer (score 2):

each script should have :

```
<script src="xxx" type="text/javascript">
```

also add this line and tell what it says :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
   alert('1');
});
</script>
```